# MongoDb: Search value in ranges in different situations

Tags: mongodb

First.

We have follows records in db

```
{ _id:1, values: [ 1 ,5 ,6 ,8]},
{ _id:2, values: [5 ,7 ,8,10 ,40 ,1]},
{ _id:3, values: [50 ,60 ,5 ,1 ]}
```

I need query all records whitch consist 'values' from range 8 - 10. Result must be `{_id:1},{_id:2}`

`query ({values:{'$gte':8,'$lte':10}})` return all records and it is not correct result, due to 'values' is array!!

Second.

We have follows records in db

```
{_id:1, from: 1, to:100},
{_id:2, from: 101, to:200},
{_id:3, from: 201, to:300},
{_id:4, from: 301, to:400} ...
```

I need found records with element 205  within range from-to . Result {_id:3}

```
query({from:{'$lte':205},to:{'$gte':205})
```

is very slow and dont use any indexes `{from:1,to:1}` at all;

I'm a bit confused. Can anybody help, please.

THank you.

Comment: Are you sure in your range query you don't have any other fields in the predicate? What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 3):

### Case 1: Range query over array values

EDIT: i did the test using wrong values.

As [documentation explains](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#array), using conditional operators over array values (AND implicit operator), only needs to match one condition to return the document.

So,

- _id:1 matches $lte and $gte clauses: **OK**
- _id:2 matches $lte and $gte clauses: **OK**
- _id:3 matches only $lte (5 < 10 and 1 < 10) clause: **NOT OK** but works as intended as the documentation explains.

If you need to filter using this range queries over the array values you have to wrap the values using objects, as follows:

```
db.test_col2.insert({values:[{v:1} ,{v:5 },{v:6} ,{v:8}]})
db.test_col2.insert({values:[{v:5 },{v:7} ,{v:8},{v:10 },{v:40} ,{v:1}]})
db.test_col2.insert({values: [{v:50} ,{v:60} ,{v:5} ,{v:1} ]})
db.test_col2.find({values: {$elemMatch:{v:{$lte:10, $gte:8}}} })

{"_id":ObjectId("51273098140d09d9105739b5"),"values":[{"v":1},{"v":5},{"v":6},{"v":8}]}
{"_id":ObjectId("51273098140d09d9105739b6"),"values":[{"v":5},{"v":7},{"v":8},{"v":10},{"v":40},{"v":1}]}
```

If you want to use an index for this query, you can do it as follows:

```
db.test_col2.ensureIndex({"values.v":1})
db.test_col2.find({values: {$elemMatch:{v:{$lte:10, $gte:8}}} }).explain()
{
  "cursor": "BtreeCursor values.v_1",
  "isMultiKey": true,
...
}
```

### Case 2: Hitting the index using open ranges

As you can see this query hits the index as expected.

```
for(var i=0 ; i<120000 ; i++) {
... db.test_col.insert({from: (Math.random()*100)%100, to: (Math.random()*100)%100});
... }
> db.test_col.ensureIndex({from:1, to:1})
> db.test_col.count()
120002
> db.test_col.find({from:{$gte:3}, to:{$lt:60}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor from_1_to_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 69741,
    "nscannedObjects" : 69902,
    "nscanned" : 116563,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 340,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "from" : [
            [
                3,
                1.7976931348623157e+308
            ]
        ],
        "to" : [
            [
                -1.7976931348623157e+308,
                60
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "new-host-2.home:27017"
}
```

Comment: Yes, we talking about 2.2. In Case 1, if you insert in second record 0 value - query return both records. In case 2, 340ms for 120000 records to slow. In my case, table have 2,500,000 records and it take about 10sec.

Comment: The queries you are talking about are the real queries? Or you just simplified it to explain your problem? I said this because i executed your queries locally and get the expected behaviour, as i said in my post.

Comment: Yes, simplified. But look at my answer with your example.

Comment: fixed! I have tested and you were right. I added a solution to this using $elemMatch but you need to change the schema.

Comment: [{'value':0},{'value':5},{'value':6}] ?

Comment: Yes, but take into account that shorter field names takes less hard disk space. So, use the shorter field name always you be able to.

Comment: You no need to change the schema,$elemMatch should work, Please check my answer..

Answer (score 0):

In Case 1:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: xxx:9900/test
mongos> db.col2.insert({values:[1,2,3]})
mongos> db.col2.insert({values:[0,5,6]})
mongos> db.col2.find({values:{$lte:3, $gte:1}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51272120d96837944b3a2097"), "values" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5127212bd96837944b3a2098"), "values" : [ 0, 5, 6 ] }
```

For me, its incorrect. 0 5 6 not in range 1-3.

Comment: mongos> db.col2.find({'$elemMatch':{values:{$lte:3, $gte:1}}})
mongos> db.col2.find({'$elemMatch':{values:{$lte:3},values:{ $gte:1}}}) return nothing

Comment: db.col2.find({'$elemMatch':{values:{$lte:3},values:{ $gte:1}}}) --> This won't technically work as doing two different operations on the same field like this is not supported, $elemMatch exists for the same reason !! Please check my answer..

Answer (score 0):

I know this late but as suggested no need to change schema, answering as this might help someone like me who came across later point of time :

**Case 1: Range query over array values**

```
db.getCollection('your collection').find({values :{$elemMatch :{$gte: 8, $lt: 10}}}, {_id:1})
```

Basically here we're wrapping two conditions on same array field **values** using $elemMatch and a second filter/condition to .find is a projection which says output should only contain **_id**.

Appreciate others for their answers/help..